# Load google.com to my site

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I want to load google.com into a page in my site.
I tried using iframe but it doesn't work google.com.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

didn't work.

How can I load the contents of google.com to my page?
I don't care if the solution uses PHP, javascript or simple HTML.

I know that the iframe can't work im trying to figure a way around it.

edit:
I want the hole page to load. It's not for fishing its just for fun. I want to find a way around the iframe block.

Comment: Google doesn't allow its site to be in a frame (`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`).  Why do you want to load Google in a frame?

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? Do you mean it didn't show up visually? If so try setting some size dimensions on the iframe as it may be loading and just not appearing.

Comment: I know that the iframe can't work im trying to figure a way around it

Comment: Google uses `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` on most of their pages. This makes it impossible for anyone other than Google itself to load Google in an iframe.

Comment: you can load it in PHP with a proxy, check out http://www.phpmyproxy.com/ ... anyhow why would you even need to do this? phishing? getting around nanny software? why?

Comment: Are you trying to be able to use the search function for google on your page,  or do you want the whole page to render inside of your page for some reason?

Comment: I guess they use some kind of "frame breaker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a search input which submits to Google, here's a possible way to go: http://www.google.com/cse/tools/create_onthefly

But don't forget that this does not include Google to your site - that is simply a form which will send the user to Google. He won't be on your site then anymore.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the search function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are probably different options for this, but usually one want to have the searchbox only, not he entire page.

A simple way to embed a google search box on your site is by using the following markup:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">

<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="q" size="25"
 maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
<input type="checkbox"  name="sitesearch"
 value="yourwebsite.com" checked />Search on yourwebsite<br />
</td></tr></table>
</div>

</form>
```

As you can see, there is even an option to have google restrict the search to your website. Unfortunately, the results will redirect on google itself, they will not be embedded in your site, I am not sure if this is allowed by their usage policy.

Hope that helps, good-luck.